# Question about how to make onResume() run onCreate() code

Tags: android

I am new to android. 
I have a question about onResume(). How to make my activity rerun code in onCreate() after back from the 2nd activity?(Example i have updated some data in activity2 and wish to refresh activity1 to run code in onCreate() after back from activity2) Anyway better practice instead of retype code in onCreate() to onResume(). Sorry for my bad English grammar and thank in advance.

Comment: just make both methods call the same method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the part you wish to run in `onResume()` and `onCreate()` into a separate function, then call that function both in `onCreate()` and `onResume()`.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle b){
    //Code specific to onCreate call
    //...
    //Invoke the common function
    commonFunction();
}

protected void onResume(){
    //Invoke the common function here as well
    commonFunction();
}
private void commonFunction(){
    //piece of code you want to execute in both onCreate and onResume
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I have another question to ask. Why my application will run onCreate() and onResume() at the movement I launch the activity? Is it only onCreate will execute, i have asynctask in onCreate() not sure because asynctask triggered onResume(). Thanks !

Comment: If you have questions about Activity Lifecycles, please refer to [this article](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle). It explains the process of launching activities and the order of invoked lifecycle events really well.